# Too many re-renders React native

Tags: react-native, draggable

Hello I try to duplicate a view by press on a "draggable item". I've got it working on a "components function". But when I use Hooks it not works, it gives me an error:

"Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop."

This is the view who I try add:

```
  const addNewPLayer = () => {
    return (
      <Draggable
        x={240}
        y={300}
        renderSize={20}
        renderColor="red"
        renderText="u"
      />
    );
  };
```

This is my add function:

```
 const [newplayer, setNewPlayer] = useState([]);

  const addPlayer = () => {
    setNewPlayer([...newplayer, <addNewPLayer />]);
  };
```

This my "button", onShortPressRelease works like onPress.

```
   <Draggable
      key={key}
      x={"80%"}
      y={50}
      renderColor="blue"
      renderSize={50}
      isCircle
      renderText={item.name}
      onShortPressRelease={addPlayer()}
    />
```

And to display this view a just added my state

```
{newplayer}
```

What doing I'am wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not test everything with what you sent, but the first thing that strikes me is the `<Draggable />` component.
In its props `onShortPressRelease` you **instantaneously** call the `addPlayer` function, I do believe what you want would be either

```
<Draggable
  ...
  onShortPressRelease={addPlayer}
/>
```

or

```
<Draggable
  ...
  onShortPressRelease={() => addPlayer()}
```

so that it adds a player only when you actually release the key.

This is important because if `Draggable` is rendered with everything else, it would call `setPlayer` function, triggering a new render, re-rendering `Draggable`, which would again rerender... thus resulting in an infinite render loop.